# Timeouts when attempting to post answers?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

When attempting to answer [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/c-library-for-converting-geom-field-of-sqlserver-into-set-of-google-latlng) this morning, I am getting timeouts. It took me several minutes to compose the answer - is there a time limit on that maybe? FireFox 9.0.1 (I'm on Win7) gives me the classic "Connection Reset" error, while Chrome 16.0.912.77 m gives me:

> Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

I have cleared caches, logged out of GIS.se, restarted both browsers, nothing works. Hell, I even tried IE9 (which shows true desperation), and got a timeout there as well. When I go back to the post, I always see part of my original answer in the composition box:

[image]

But again, that is only part of the answer that I was trying to submit.

This has occurred before, but I shrugged it off as a glitch. It seems like no matter what I try, I will not be able to post the answer.

Also, found this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105607/whats-with-the-timeouts-on-particular-questions) on meta.so that looks like the same issue from Sept 2011.

UPDATE:

I was able to post the answer from a different machine, at home to be precise, so a different network as well.

Comment: Having no issues (Firefox 10, Chrome 16.0.912.77) had any ISP issues lately?

Comment: @Mapperz - we have blips every so often, but that still wouldn't address the fact that I cannot go back and answer that post when everything else appears to be working just fine.

Comment: Not a solution, but a suggestion ... I use Notepad to compose longer answers and even emails for that matter, then copy and paste.  I have been stung by many web-based time-outs (not this site though) and losing a long response is a pain.

Comment: @DanPatterson - Good idea. I could see the timeout coming, so I was able to salvage my complete answer by copying it into a text file. Still, can't go back and re-post it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at our Haproxy logs, I am seeing quite a few connections from your work on the 2nd of Feb that were taking upwards of 10 seconds to even talk to our servers.

This indicates that internet at work was "patchy" at the time.

Nothing much we can do here to improve it.

Comment: Thanks Sam, shoulda figured that was it. But what about not being able to repost the answer at all except from a different pc/network?